# How to unwrap more than one Map<String,String> to Json

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

How to unwrap more than one Map to JSON. Example

```
public class Class {
Map<String,String> firstMap;
Map<String,String> secondMap;
}
```

I can use @JsonAnyGetter only for one Map  field. I know also that I can use custom Serializer, but I've got more fields in class for which I don't want to change the deserialization method.
Preferable JSON output:

```
{
    "Name": "Name",
    "LastName": "LastName",
    "firstMapKey": "firstMapValue"
    "secondMapKey": "secondMapValue"
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
    "Name": "Name",
    "LastName": "LastName",
    "firstMap": {
        "firstMapKey": "firstMapValue"
    },
    "secondMap": {
        "secondMapKey": "secondMapValue"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain with more details your question? I don't understand it.

Comment: An example of the JSON structure you're aiming for would be very useful

Comment: Don't want to have nested fields of both Map<String, String>  in the JSON file after mapper.writeValue... I just want to have flat Json with fields from these two maps and other String fields on one level.

Comment: @PiotrSupel an example of JSON of how it's now and how you want to be, will be helpful.

Comment: Sure, I've just added more details

Comment: You could always `@JsonIgnore` the existing maps and have a separate 'merged' map containing the keys and values from the other maps combined, then use your existing `@JsonAnyGetter` method to make it work for just that map

Comment: @PiotrSupel I don't think you can do that with jackson(by default). Map it's like an array. Most probably you should override the way how jackson serialize a Map. Or create your own method which build JSON how you want.

Comment: @JonK thank you! I've added a map with JsonAnyGetter and merge both mentioned maps into it (for which I've added annotation JsonIgnore). Problem solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@JonK helped me: I've added one additional Map and merge both Maps into it. For the additional map, I used @JsonAnyGetter and @JsonIgnore for both Maps used to merge.

```
public class Class {
    @JsonIgnore
    Map<String,String> firstMap;
    @JsonIgnore
    Map<String,String> secondMap;

    Map<String,String> compositeMap

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, String> getCompositeMap() {
        return compositeMap;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setCompositeMap(Map<String, String> compositeMap) {
        this.compositeMap = compositeMap;
    }

}
```

Comment: This should work fine for POJO -> JSON, but you'll have to write some additional code to recreate the `firstMap` and `secondMap` objects when going from JSON -> POJO. If it doesn't actually matter it's probably even easier to just ditch `firstMap` and `secondMap` entirely and just use the `compositeMap` exclusively

Comment: @JonK could you please show what exactly do you mean by "just ditch firstMap and secondMap entirely and just use the compositeMap ". Please have in mind that it is just a simple example. This class is out from Solr DB and has dynamic fields reflecting firstMap and secondMap in it.  I'm getting it using findAll in DB. After all operations I set compositeMap before mapper.writeValue... Do you know better solution?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing your setup in much greater detail, but basically if you can do everything that you need with `compositeMap` you could probably delete `firstMap` and `secondMap` from the class. Might not be an option though, you know your codebase, I don't.

Comment: @JonK Solr DB serves me dynamic fields for firstMap and for secondMap. Both are comming from external API so deleting these fields is not an option. However your solution is very helpful and seems to be the best solution.